# Track fragments with Google Analytics v4

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 fragments in my app and I want to log every time one of them is displayed. This is what I have in the onResume() in each fragment class:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AppController application = (AppController) getActivity().getApplication();
        mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
}

@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mTracker != null) {
            mTracker.setScreenName("Fragment_1");
            mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
            mTracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
        }
        Log.i("RESUME", "Fragment_1");
    }
```

However, when the app is launched, I receive all the three logs and when I scroll to another fragment, the onResume is not activated. I believe what happens is when the app is launched then all three fragments are loaded (I see that the data are downloaded from my server to populate the lists in the other 2 even if I'm just looking at the first fragment) and that's why onResume is not called when I scroll to the other fragments.

[This](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-integrating-google-analytics-v4/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786274/andoird-using-google-analytics-v4-to-track-fragment) is no different from this approach.